# Como extrair informação via expressão regular?

Tags: regex

Tenho a seguinte string:

`adapter-UDP02_sistem10_a.log`

Como extrair o trecho **UDP02** via expressão regular? Sendo que a lógica é: capturar tudo que estiver após o **-** (hífen) e antes do primeiro **_** (underline)

Comment: Se seguir este padrão em que o hífen `-` vem antes do underline `_`, [esta regex](https://regex101.com/r/NhDzks/2) pode ser usada: `[^-_]+?(?=_)`, em que somente o primeiro full match pode ser capturado. Mas em casos como: `error_adapter-UDP02_system10_a.log` não funcionaria. Então creio que a resposta do Valdeir com a utilização dos grupos é a mais adequada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize `-(.*?)_`.

`-` Inicia a seleção a parti do hífen

`(.*?)_` Aqui o sinal de `?` vai limitar até a primeira ocorrência do `_`

**[Demonstração](https://regex101.com/r/wvLCvO/1)**
**[Demonstração com PHP](https://ideone.com/woq6p2)**
**[Demonstração com Java](https://ideone.com/8PDy2K)**

**Demonstração com JavaScript**

```js
const regex = new RegExp("-(.*?)_");
const value = "adapter-UDP02_sistem10_a.log";

let result = value.match(regex);

console.log( result[1] );
```

Comment: No regex online ele tá retornando 2 grupos (full Match e Group 1), é possível retornar somente o valor UDP02

Comment: Basta capturar o grupo. '-'. Ex: https://ideone.com/woq6p2 **ou** https://ideone.com/8PDy2K .

Comment: @FábioJânio A resposta é essa mesma. Vc não vai conseguir pegar sem grupo. O JS só aceita lookbehind no Chrome (até onde eu sei). Acho que com lookbehind daria pra pegar sem grupo.